# How to solve Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component warning in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

i get the warning can't call setstate on an unmounted component. I get this when i fetch the file from server in componentdidUpdate and set state. I do so to load data automatically instead of page refresh. I don't know how to avoid the warning.

Below is the code,

```
class ClassName extends React.PureComponent {
    _ismounted = false;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.default_item_ = {
            name: 'Items',
            index: 0,
            children: [],
        };
        this.state = {
            items: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._ismounted = true;
        this.load_items();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this._ismounted = true;
        this.load_items();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._ismounted = false;
        this.unlisten_path_change();
    }

    load_items = () => {
        const file_name = 'file_name.json';
        client.get_file(this.props.item_id, file_name, 'json')
            .then((request) => {
                const items = request.response;
                this.default_root_item.children = items;
                if (this._ismounted) {
                    this.setState({ items: [this.default_root_item] });
                }
                this.handle_path_change(this.props.location.pathname);
            })
    };
}


handle_path_change = (new_path) => {
    if (new_path === this.last_location_pathname) {      
        return;
    }
    this.last_location_pathname = new_path;

    if (new_path.indexOf('/items/') < 0) {
        if (this.state.items_expanded) {
            this.handle_item_close();
        }
        return;
    }
    let item_id = parseInt(new_path.replace(/^.*\/items\//, 
    '').replace(/\D*$/, ''));
    if (isNaN(item_id) || item_id < 0) {
        item_id = 0;
    }
    const item = ClassName.find_item_recursively(this.state.items, 
    item_id);
    this.handle_root_item_change(item);
};
```

What i have tried to do?

I used the _ismounted variable to keep track of the component mount. However, this doesn't work. Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are you still getting the warning message or are you not seeing the behaviour that is expected? I found this article which talks about this in detail: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-warning-cant-call-setstate-on-an-unmounted-component/

Comment: @chirag Ravindra: its not working as expected and also i see the warning

Comment: what is`this.handle_path_change` doing?

Comment: @aseferov: updated the question...it actually works like breadcrumb navigation.clicking each item would display its children in the layout.

Comment: Where is `handle_path_change` coming from? It doesn't appear to be inside the component class. Also what is `layer_id` ? Is that a typo for `item_id`. Can you .create a JS fiddle which reproduces this issue? Otherwise this will go back and forth forever